# Binding Value From Database to Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I am new to WPF MVVM. I have a `DataGrid`. When am clicking on that `DataGrid` row i got access to the column value named employee id. Then I need to bind all the row values to corresponding TextBoxes for update purpose. I have attached a command to the loaded event of the window. But the employee id value get reset to null when entering into the method for binding.

This is my HomeViewModel

```
private DataRowView _SelectedRow;
        public DataRowView SelectedRow
        {
            get
            {
                return _SelectedRow;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_SelectedRow != value)
                {
                    _SelectedRow = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRow");
                }
            }
         }
```

This is my method

```
public void bindControlValues()
        {
            int id=Convert.ToInt32( SelectedRow.Row["Emp_ID"]);

            try
            {
                sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Connection.connectionstring);
                sqlConnection.Open();
                selectCommand = new SqlCommand(AppConstants.StoredProcedures.GetDataProcedure);
                selectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                selectCommand.Parameters.Add(AppConstants.Parameters.Emp_ID, SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;

                sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand);
                sqlDataSet = new DataSet();
                sqlAdapter.Fill(sqlDataSet);
                employee.FirstName = sqlDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
                employee.LastName = sqlDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][2].ToString();
                employee.Dob = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString());
                employee.Age = Convert.ToInt32(sqlDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][4].ToString());
                employee.Street1 = sqlDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][5].ToString();
                employee.Street2 = sqlDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][6].ToString();
                employee.City = sqlDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][7].ToString();
                employee.State = sqlDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][8].ToString();
                employee.ZipCode = sqlDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][9].ToString();
                employee.PhoneNumber = sqlDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][10].ToString();
                employee.MobileNumber = sqlDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][11].ToString();
                employee.Email = sqlDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][12].ToString();
                employee.Web = sqlDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][13].ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlConnection.Close();
                selectCommand.Dispose();
                sqlDataSet.Dispose();
            }

        }
```

This is my xaml code

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding BindControlValueCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>



<TextBox  Name="txtFirstName" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">

<TextBox Name="txtLastName" Text="{Binding Path=LastName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"></TextBox>
```

Comment: Generally speaking, binding database straight to UI isn't smart. are you farmiliar with [Three layer architecture](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36847/Three-Layer-Architecture-in-C-NET)?

Comment: actually am doing it through properties..

Comment: it is in different window...i am not getting that id..it is resetting to null.i hav a window say Home,that has a datagrid..and a button say 'Update' for updation..when am selecting the row in a datagrid Selected Row property got the values Containing employee information.like firstname,lastname,id etc...when update button is clicked,it gets reset to null that is selected row property..how can i access employee id to the updation window..help me..pls...

Comment: I need to update those values..what shud i do..

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your textbox in same window that has datagrid or in different window.

Comment: it is in different window...i am not getting that id..it is resetting to null.i hav a window say Home,that has a datagrid..and a button say 'Update' for updation..when am selecting the row in a datagrid Selected Row property got the values Containing employee information.like firstname,lastname,id etc...when update button is clicked,it gets reset to null that is selected row property..how can i access employee id to the updation window..help me..pls...